# Need to partition free space after clone on mbp

Tags: partition, ssd

I cloned my MacBook Pro 1 TB SSD to a 2 TB SSD. The new SSD shows up just like the old one. 
How do I add the unallocated free space (~1 TB) on the new SSD to the main volume?

```
technicgal1:~ Technicgal1$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 97A5C3A5-484A-40CF-9E73-6251095F1DA2
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.1 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage SSHD                    999.3 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s3
/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS SSHD2TB                +999.0 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                 DA8E726B-6383-4470-BE08-97745C29D5DA
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
technicgal1:~ Technicgal1$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (2 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 4322AA94-E294-4F72-B6F8-D6BA40A51408
|   =========================================================
|   Name:         Macintosh HD
|   Status:       Online
|   Size:         250140434432 B (250.1 GB)
|   Free Space:   9445376 B (9.4 MB)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume 94A7EE4F-CFC7-44BE-8A6A-83ABECAC3417
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    0
|   |   Disk:     disk0s2
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     250140434432 B (250.1 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume Family 35483A58-9E0E-45ED-9317-7F22F7B49F6F
|       ----------------------------------------------------------
|       Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
|       Encryption Status:       Unlocked
|       Conversion Status:       Complete
|       High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
|       |                        Passphrase Required
|       |                        Accepts New Users
|       |                        Has Visible Users
|       |                        Has Volume Key
|       |
|       +-> Logical Volume 97A5C3A5-484A-40CF-9E73-6251095F1DA2
|           ---------------------------------------------------
|           Disk:                  disk1
|           Status:                Online
|           Size (Total):          249769230336 B (249.8 GB)
|           Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
|           Revert Status:         Reboot required
|           LV Name:               Macintosh HD
|           Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
|           Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 42B22334-B408-4A14-881A-59085EFA8574
    =========================================================
    Name:         SSHD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         999345127424 B (999.3 GB)
    Free Space:   6062080 B (6.1 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 88553EA4-D22B-46CA-9F86-7C8CE46D529E
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk2s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999345127424 B (999.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family BAEB0215-349C-4DC6-A03A-7AE4057DF831
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume DA8E726B-6383-4470-BE08-97745C29D5DA
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk3
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          998982549504 B (999.0 GB)
            Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
            LV Name:               SSHD2TB
            Volume Name:           SSHD2TB
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
technicgal1:~ Technicgal1$
```

OS X 10.11.6 is installed on SSHD2TB.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46272/discussion-on-question-by-carrie-fraser-need-to-partition-free-space-after-clone).

Answer (score 1):

To add the unallocated disk space of the 2 TB SSD to the volume SSHD2TB you have to resize the whole CoreStorage stack SSHD (which contains the Logical Volume Group 42B22334-B408-4A14-881A-59085EFA8574, the Physical Volume 88553EA4-D22B-46CA-9F86-7C8CE46D529E, the Logical Volume Family BAEB0215-349C-4DC6-A03A-7AE4057DF831 and the Logical Volume DA8E726B-6383-4470-BE08-97745C29D5DA):

- Boot to Macintosh HD. After entering your password the system will boot to your desktop. Now you should be asked for the password of SSHD2TB to unlock it. Enter this password.
- Open Disk Utility and verify/repair SSHD2TB.
- Open Terminal.app and enter `diskutil list`.
- With the disk identifier of the 2 TB SSD (in your example disk2) enter:

  ```
  diskutil info disk2 | grep "Total Size"
  ```

  this will yield something like:

  ```
  Total Size:      2.0 TB (2000390717440 Bytes) (exactly 3907013120 512-Byte-Units)
  ```
- Then enter `diskutil cs list`.
- You will get a similar or identical output as in your question.
- To resize the whole stack use the command `diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID size` with lvUUID= the Logical Volume UUID of SSHD2TB and size: the final size in t (TeraByte), g (GigaByte), m (MegaByte) etc.

  Now you have to subtract the size of the EFI and the Recovery HD from the found total size to get *size*: ~2000391 MB - 210 MB - 650 MB = 1999531 MB.
  In this case the command is then:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack DA8E726B-6383-4470-BE08-97745C29D5DA 1999531m
  ```

  If you get an error:

  ```
  Error: -69720: There is not enough free space in the Core Storage Logical Volume Group for this operation
  ```

  simply choose a slightly smaller size like 1999525m instead and reenter the command with this value.

  In some rare cases a magic size of `0g` also works:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack DA8E726B-6383-4470-BE08-97745C29D5DA 0g
  ```

  This will expand the stack to the max size possible.

  Both commands resize the whole CoreStorage stack and move the Recovery HD on the 2 TB disk (in your example disk2s3) to the end of the disk.