# Mac not booting in OS X. Partition showing FFFFF-FFFF

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, partition

I did the same thing as mentioned by the poster of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/307040#307040) question and I am facing the same problem. My Mac is not booting in OS X and I am unable to find the startup disk also. I gave the same commands and found that the partition type is changed as OP's.

[image]

Comment: @klanomath I did not try your answer as I don't see partition 3 and 4 as other have. I have only 0,1,2 and partition 2 is my main which has data(Which has partition type as FFFF…). I wanted to be sure before trying out anything.

Comment: @akm You should add some details like the HD type of disk0  (e.g. SSD), the installed system on disk0s2 (and disk1s2 which seems to be a second **working** boot drive), whether disk0s2 was encrypted etc. If you need further (personal) assistance you'd have to download & install [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com) and send me an email with your TeamViewer credentials

Comment: @klanomath 
**1)** disk0 is my internal drive which is SSD. 
**2)** I pressed alt/option button while reboot which displayed 4 options(backup from time machine, get online help, reinstall os x, disk utility). Here I chose to reinstall os x by inserting a external hard disk(which is HDD) and i installed it on the external hard disk(since internal SSD was not showing here). Now, after inserting the external hard drive, if I reboot my system, it is automatically booting from external drive(which is OS X Lion). 
**3)** I think, disk0s2 is not encrypted.

Comment: @akm You still didn't mention the original but "vanished" system on disk0s2! Did you upgrade it to High Sierra previously? I recommend to upgrade your "temporary recovery system" on disk1s2 from Lion to Mavericks or much better: High Sierra - if possible. After upgrading Lion to High Sierra we will attack the main problem.

Comment: Original is sierra. I am upgrading to El Captain in external HDD then will update to High Seirra as we can't directly goto High sierra from 10.7.5 Lion :)

Comment: @akm If the original on disk0s2 was Sierra, Sierra on disk1s2 is sufficient

Comment: @klanomath Installed sierra on external HDD. ready with team viewer, how can i contact u ?