# macOS partition not mounted (FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF)

Tags: startup, partition, mount

After upgrading to High Sierra, my Macintosh_HD partition got corrupted.
Only Windows was working so I got into terminal from internet recovery.
And corrected the FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF partition type. (I used instructions from other similar posts)

Here are the details after I corrected disk0s2 partition type, which was FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF.

[image]

And that picture is from `diskutil list` command:

[image]

Right now neither Windows nor macOS is working.

But booting from a bootable macOS USB I can manage to reach the Windows partition. Disk0s2 is not mountable. I suppose there is some problem with MBR.

Can I solve this issue?

Comment: Since your partition table is missing a recovery partition (disk0s3 with 650 MB) I suspect that the partition type of disk0s2 is wrong. It has to be 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (=APFS). Probably related: [Partition Type : FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310744/partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basicaly i will gpt destroy disk0 then add the partitions again but in disk0s3 i will add 7c3**** and disk0s4 as ebd0****.

Comment: No, your disk0s1 stays C1... disk0s2 becomes 7C.. and disk0s3 stays EB... You don't have to add an additional partition. The missing recovery partition is just an indicator that disks0s2 is an APFS container (which contains a different type of recovery volume, with no traces in  the partition table).

Comment: I changed disk0s2 to 7C... Now disk0s2 type name shows as 7c345... and verify disk gives no error. but verify disk0s2 from disk utility gives verify volume failed. Unrecognized file system error.

Comment: System version is Lion 10.7.5.

Comment: Can i repair it from internet recovery?

Comment: verifyVolume at the Internet recovery mode gives error; (Unrecognized file system (-69846)

Comment: Sorry, i should checked first. System version in internet recovery is also 10.7.5

Comment: Still no disk at boot after NVRAM reset.

Comment: Last resort: can you install a full macOS High Sierra to a thumb drive (16 GB should be sufficient, better 32 GB) or an external drive and install TeamViewer 12 (not 13!). Then you can invite me to a remote session and I may have look at the content of disk0. But don't post any credentials here. I will give you my email address later.

Comment: Ok at the moment I have a TeamViewer session with Mexico City ;-)

Comment: Thanks to Klanomath, I recovered important stuff from the corrupted drive and installed High Sierra. Thank you Klanomath, You are great. :)