# Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF appeared when tried to remove Linux(UBUNTU 18.04) from dual boot from Mac

Tags: disk-utility, partition, startup

I earlier had dual-booted my MacBook Pro(2013), Catalina OS with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I wished to remove it, so I erased the unwanted partition in disk utility and restarted my mac, it did not show the macOS symbol in refind so I started in internet recovery mode. Afterwards, I

[image]

followed step by step till the step where I removed my third and second partitions.
Since my MacBook is working on Catalina OS and the guide was given according to the Sierra, I refrained from going further.
Please help me out since I'm not that terminal savvy.

[image]

Comment: This is the (more or less) proper duplicate: [Unable to boot into Mac OSX after updating dual-boot Ubuntu, Partition Type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349399/unable-to-boot-into-mac-osx-after-updating-dual-boot-ubuntu-partition-type-ffff)

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the second and the third partition:

   ```
   gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0
   gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
   ```
2. Add the (former) second partiton with the proper size and partition type:

   ```
   gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 461916744 -t apfs /dev/disk0
   ```
3. Check disk0 and the resulting synthesized APFS container scheme with diskutil:

   ```
   diskutil list #get the deviceID of the APFS container scheme
   diskutil verifyDisk disk0
   diskutil verifyVolume diskX #diskX: deviceID of the APFS container scheme
   ```

Assuming you want to resize the APFS container to the full size of the disk (500 GB) you have to enter:

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```