# How to completely remove unwanted Ubuntu dual boot partition?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, startup

I previously had a dual boot (Linux and macOS) setup. I added UBUNTU and SWAP partitions to the existing macOS partition.

I no longer need Linux so I deleted the UBUNTU partition but I still see the SWAP  partition. It doesn't look like I can delete the SWAP partition and my macOS partition is now named `disk0s2`.

Can you help remove all remnants of UBUNTU and SWAP partitions so that I just have the macOS partition. (I'm running out of disk space when downloading so I want to free up disk space).

Here are some images from Disk Utility
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: After using the Disk Utility to delete, often you need to quit and then reopen the Disk Utility to get the correct results. Apple has fixed this problem with the new Apple Silicon Macs by making it impossible to install Ubuntu. Usually, posting the output from the command `diskutil list` is more useful than posting images of the Disk Utility.

Comment: I should warn you that you probably will not be able to restart your Mac. I believe this to be true, because in the images you posted `Physical stores:` is showing `--`. In other words, there is a good chance the partition type for `disk0s2` has be changed to `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF appeared when tried to remove Linux(UBUNTU 18.04) from dual boot from Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381887/partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-appeared-when-tried-to-remo). However, the command `gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 461916744 -t apfs /dev/disk0` given in klanomath's answer would need to be updated with the correct integer values.

Comment: Also, spuggy has not mentioned anything about removing the Ubuntu boot files from the hidden EFI partition. This would be part of a complete Ubuntu removal.