# MacOS partition would not boot/mount

Tags: partition, startup, recovery

So.

I have a mid-2015 MacBook Pro (15'') running macOS 11.
Recently, I wanted to set up a dual-boot with Debian. It worked and I could boot on the two systems.
I've done some sh... weird things and now the EFI of Debian isn't recognized by the system, also the Mac APFS Partition is unmounted, and not mountable because **the Recovery system OF THE MAC** (not the one on the Macintosh APFS Partition) **is from 2015 so pre-APFS**. I'm stuck with this screen or the old Recovery partition. I have on another disk a disk image of the COMPLETE Macintosh Partition (not only the data). [image: The screen on my mac] Can someone help me to mount the disk image in APFS and put it on my mac (making it bootable) ? Thanks !!!!

PS: Yes, it's the same problem as [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310744/partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff), but the answer isn't understandable. So don't give me some commands without explanations, please.

PPS: If you need more infos, ask under this post.

Comment: What is not understandable about the answer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mmmmmm I'm not a professional about shell and English isn't my native language, so I can't understand what the command does and I don't want to execute commands that I don't understand. I need that someone explain to me what is the objective of each command.

Comment: Have you looked at the man pages for gpt? Each group of commands does have a description in that answer giving the objective

Comment: Have you try boot in internet recovery mode **cmd + alt + r** ?

Comment: @Jean_JD Internet Recovery is by default chose when I boot in Recovery (don't know why)

Comment: So, in Recovery Mode, can you see your internal disk organization? From the top menu Utilities/terminal, can you give the results of the command `diskutil list`?

Comment: The result is too long, even with cuts, I'll give you a file on github with the results in a few minutes.

Comment: https://github.com/omerien/omerien/blob/main/applestackexchage.1

Comment: OK. Can you add the results of command : `gpt -r show disk2`

Comment: https://github.com/omerien/omerien/blob/main/applestackexchange.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try from the terminal in Recovery Mode, modify the ffff partition by apfs structure. The commands are :

```
diskutil umountDisk disk2
```

then

```
gpt remove -i 2 disk2
```

then

```
diskutil umountDisk disk2
```

then

```
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 820414520 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk2
```

then you give the result of

```
diskutil list internal
```

Comment: It actually worked ! Here's the results of the last command : https://github.com/omerien/omerien/blob/main/applestackexchange.3. Thank you so much !

Comment: Great. Happy for you. ;-}