# Unable to boot from SSD but can still access files

Tags: macos, partition, startup

Yesterday, I was attempting to update to Catalina, I was using macOS 10.12.6 on my Macbook Pro Retina 13-inch Late 2013 model. When running the installer it asked me to select a disk to install it onto, but there was nothing there. I looked online for some information and thought maybe the fact I'm dual-booting is causing an issue. I deleted my Linux partitions, but it still wouldn't work so I restarted my computer and a whole host of issues soon followed.

I booted into Internet Recovery Mode and my CoreStorage partition wasn't named "Macintosh HD" anymore and the "TYPE" was now a string of f's. I created a removable boot drive using an SD card and followed [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff) until I was able to successfully mount my CoreStorage partition and access my files.

Now, my current issue is what I should do next. I'd like to be able to boot up from my main drive again without having to completely reinstall macOS and overwrite everything on my SSD. Thankfully, I have access to all the files on it so I can back everything up if needed. Although I'd like to avoid spending the next couple days backing up data, reinstalling software, and recovering documents.

Entering `diskutil list` into the terminal gives me these results:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            460.4 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *63.9 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Untitled 1              63.0 GB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS macOS SD               +62.6 GB    disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2
                                 CC5B450E-DC92-4F6C-A1BB-B1E52E138204
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk3 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +460.0 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 5A57468C-6E2D-41B2-A76E-08EA31850672
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```