# Data not backed up, System not booting, Getting Error: -69845 after trying to fix bad Partition Type

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, partition, unix, dual-boot

A few months ago someone installed Linux on my computer using rEFInd for a project. I am using a 2015 13" Macbook Pro with 256GB SSD. The partition for linux was made to be 60GB. After the project I somehow deleted rEFInd and completely forgot about the rest.

A few days ago I noticed that I had only 190GB of fully usable space and remembered that Linux was probably still there. After trying to use **diskutil** I thought deleting the Linux partition and resizing the Apple AFS partition everything would work. But sadly after deleting it,the partition with my data on had type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF on my main bootable drive. Now after restarting my computer I get a black screen followed by GRUB Minimal Bash screen.

After following instructions on [Data Not Backed Up, Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff) I tried the commands to change my partition type to a normal OS-X partition. After doing that verifyDisk didn't give me any problems but verifying that volume returned

```
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed. 
Underlying error: 8: POSIX reports: Exec format error
```

These are the photos of **$ diskutil list** and **$ gpt -r show disk0.**

[image]
[image]

I'm not the most knowledgeable when it comes to commands like this so any help is appreciated. I have important data on the disk that I hope is not erased and won't be erased that is not backed up anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through more threads I found my own problem. The type for my partition was supposed to be APFS so by using the previous solution with the correct type as in

```
diskutil umountDisk disk0
gpt remove -i 2 disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 372637568 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
```

Now I did come across a problem at first because **diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2** gave me **Unrecognized file system (-69846)** 
I did not mind it and tried to reboot after NVRAM reset and I was able to boot back to my Macbook as I did before with no loss in data. After that I used the command :

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

in order to be able to use the memory from erasing my linux partition. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: The reason for the **Unrecognized file system (-69846)** error probably was: the sw_vers of the recovery system was 10.12 or lower (=an old recovery system not capable dealing with an APFS container)!

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot by the way, your answers helped me a lot.