# Dual boot Mac with Ubuntu using rEFInd - removed Ubuntu by deleting partition and now Mac won’t boot

Tags: mac, unix, dual-boot, efi

I had installed Ubuntu on Mac with rEFInd dual boot. I was able to use it until I thought to remove the Ubuntu.

I deleted the Ubuntu Partition from drive, and then thought it will just remove Ubuntu OS.

Since I was using rEFInd for dual boot, it cannot find the Mac drive and since Ubuntu also gone, I don’t have an OS on my Mac and I might loose my data.

[Data Not Backed Up, Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff#comment356370_282552)

Below are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried following the above link and booted Mac by installing it on Flash drive.

After verifying, I’m getting below error now:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Especially from:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath

Comment: RE: "and I might loose my data" -- Do you not have a backup?

Comment: Unfortunately, no! 