# iMac main partition disappeared after deleting a different partition

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, startup

So, I created a 20GB partition in my iMac to install Ubuntu. That worked fine, but then it turned out I needed a bit more space for the software I wanted to install, so I turned the computer off and rebooted on the main partition (Mac HD, I believe). I then deleted the 20 Gb partition, and I'm sure that's the one I deleted because I triple checked it's size, just in case. Something weird happened right away, the Mac HD partition was now being recognized as an external drive. I didn't think too much of it though, as I was more worried about the fact that those 20GB of space apparently weren't available. I then decided to restart the computer, maybe that would fix the issue. Well, the Linux partition was still there but the Mac HD option was gone -.-

Both regular and Safe boot take me to a grub command line, as well as booting the Linux partition, so it seems I actually erased it. Running diagnostics (Command-R and D keys on startup) tells me everything is fine. I also tried reseting the PRAM, to no effect.

I started the Ubuntu installation process, just to see if it would work, and when choosing where to install it there's an empty 20GB "partition" of free space, which I imagine corresponds to the partition I created and then erased, as well as 230GB partition, of which an 'unknown' amount is used.

Is there any hope of recovering the disk? I don't have a complete backup of the system, only a semi-recent backup of important work. I can live with losing some stuff, but I'd rather try to salvage it if possible, it will be quite a nuisance reinstalling all the software I use on a regular basis. If there's a way, how would I go about it? Also, if you have any idea of what might have caused this, I'd love to know.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Since no one has answered I decided to give a blind try at this, let's hope I didn't screw up.

Interestingly, while the first time i used `diskutil`the main partition was disk2, it now seems to be disk14. I haven't done anyhing else at this point, is this normal behaviour?

`diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk0s1
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk1
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk2
/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk3
/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk4
/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk7
/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk8
/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk9
/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk10
/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk11
/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk12
/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk13
/dev/disk14 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk14
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk14s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               230.8 GB   disk14s2
```

`gpt -r show disk14`

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  450721136      2  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
  451130776   39103943         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

I haven't got a clue what to look for, but I'm assuming that, since I see non-zeros, this is a CoreStorage partition. Is this correct?

`dd if=/dev/disk14s2 count=3 | vis -c`

```
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
1536 bytes transferred in 0.001849 secs (830641 bytes/sec)
\^Ber(\M-4+,\M-G\^A\0\0\0\0\0\0\0007\M-X`\0\0\0\0\0\^A\0\0\M^@\0\0\0\0NXSB\0\^P\0\0\M-.\M-.[\^C\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\M-C\^C\^Z\M^\\a6D  \M^FS\M-Ts\M-pjr\^W\M-D\M-E#\0\0\0\0\08\M-X`\0\0\0\0\0\^X\^A\0\0 l\0\0r-\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\M--\^A\0\0\0\0\0\M-:\0\0\0\M-c\^Q\0\0\M-8\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\M-@\^Q\0\0#\0\0\0,\M-D#\0\0\0\0\0qu    \0\0\0\0\0\^A\^D\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0d\0\0\0\^C\^D\0\0\0\0\0\0l\M-k\^A\0\0\0\0\0n\M-k\^A\0\0\0\0\0P\M^I\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\M^Q\M^C\M^[\^R\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\M-r$(\^C\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\00042(\^C\0\0\0\0\^A\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\^A\0\^D\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-
```

I'm still reticent to proceed, but I'll wait a bit to see if someone is able to respond...

EDIT2:
I proceeded with the assumption that I was looking at a CoreStorage partition. When verifying the disk, this was the error message I got:

`diskutil verifyVolume disk14s2`

```
Error starting file system verification for disk14s2: The given disk has a storage system (such as AppleRAID) which is not supported for this operation (-69718)
```

`diskutil verifyDisk disk14`

```
Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting
Error: -69808: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup
```

Should I continue with `diskutil repairDisk disk14` or does this error mean something else should be atempted?

EDIT3: According to David Anderson, I was actually looking at a APFS container partition. Following the steps he provided I got this:

`gpt -r show disk14`

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  450721136      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  451130776   39103943         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

Disk verification seems to be good now, but verifying the volume still returns an error, albeit a different one.

`diskutil verifyDisk disk14`

```
The partition map appears to be OK
```

`diskutil verifyVolume disk14s2`

```
Error starting file system verification for disk14s2: Unrecognized file system (-69846)
```

Should I try repairing now?

Comment: If you can boot to macOS Recovery, then post the output from `diskutil list disk0`. Or, from Ubuntu, post the output from `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` or equivalent for your internal drive.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for replying!

I was able to boot macOS Recovery, the partition doesn't show in Disk Utilities. Following your instruction on the Terminal, I got the following:
![Terminal #1](https://i.ibb.co/MVWhhD1/term-01.png).
That doesn't seem to be the right one so I tried not pointing to a specific disk and got a very long list (a total of 24 disks). I assume this is what I'm looking for:
![Terminal #2](https://i.ibb.co/35K25rp/term-02.png).

Comment: @DavidAnderson It is looking pretty similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff), although I'm not sure how much of it applies to my case or how specific that solution is. I'm really not well versed in this, and I'm afraid to make matters worse by blindly following something I don't understand, so let me know how I should proceed and if there's other useful data I can gather!

Comment: @DavidAnderson Any suggestions regarding the lastest edits? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Based on klanomath's answer to the question [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff), you should proceed as follows.

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode (or a third party drive).
- Open Terminal in the menubar Utilities > Terminal
- Get an overview with `diskutil list`.
- Assuming the disk identifier for the internal drive is still `disk14`, then enter the following commands. Otherwise, make the appropriate substitutions for the disk identifier.

  ```
   diskutil umountDisk disk14
   gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk14
   gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 450721136 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk14
  ```

Additional comments on some of your questions.

- What you thought was a CoreStorage partition is actually a Apple File System (APFS) container partition.
- The identifiers (such as `disk0` or `disk0s2`), used by commands such as `diskutil` and `gpt`, are assigned as needed. In other words, there is not permanent identifier assigned to a disk, partition, container, etc. You may need to view the output from `diskutil list` to see the current identifier assignment.

Comment: Once more, thank you for the answer! Disk verification now goes smoothly but trying to verify the volume returns a different error "Unrecognized file system (-69846)". Should I attempt repairing?