# An unknown partition type in diskutil on Mac OS : FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF Partition: How to Save data

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line, disk-utility, partition

I am using MacAir - Big Sur 2015 with 256 Gb hard drive. Hard Drive was portioned in 3: 2x 100GB (Main and Sub) as APFS and 1X 50 GB as ExFat to install Ubuntu. Later on, I decided to do partitioning of 100 GB Sub drive into 5 Gb and 95 Gb so shat I can use 5Gb drive as a shared drive to be used by both Ubuntu and Mac. I wanted to add files and access files in this 5G drive from either Ubuntu or Mac. I still don't know which Format I should use (ExFat, keep APFS or etc)

But,

I made a mistake while portioning. I had some important data on Sub drive. When I partitioned, my data stayed in 5Gb drive and now I cannot access the file. As you can see on the screenshot, isI put my data on 5 Gb partition, but I cannot see it now. Yes, data is important and I want to save it. I see that this post could help me but I cannot move forward due to following reasons. I am also new at terminal. I want to set up Ubuntu as a second OS to work.

As you can see, my partition that I need is fun of FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF. I cannot even see this 5Gb partition in DiskUtil.

[image: Terminal screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I followed the link: [How do I recover/fix my OS X partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262457/how-do-i-recover-fix-my-os-x-partition/411979#411979)

Errors I received:

I tried this command and got an error: gpt -r show disk0 gpt show: unable to open device 'disk0': Permission denied

I used following command but there is again an errorr.:
diskutil unmountdisk disk0

Unmount of disk0 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted Unmount was dissented by PID 1 (/sbin/launchd) Dissenter parent PPID 0 (kernel_task)

But I was not able to achieve the goal. What I would like to have is to have my data in this 5G drive safely and later I will take care of of shared data and install ubuntu. As you can imagine I am new in Terminal and coding. I am going to train myself in pyThon for research project and that's the reason I need Ubuntu.

thanks and regards

Comment: Terminal is just an app. I’ve changed tags and removed some of the chit chat. Have a look at the [tour] as people have a chance to decide if they can help you remotely with something.

Comment: Thank you @bmike. I did check the tour but I didn't understand well how it works. I will spend more time on it.thanks again.

Comment: Dear @klanomath hope you are doing well. I have seen your help : link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262457/how-do-i-recover-fix-my-os-x-partition/411979?noredirect=1#comment575887_411979.   I have similar problem, but I couldn't follow the lines because of some errors I got. I couldn't resolve the issues although I did search online sources. It would be great If you could help me with that. Thanks a lot in advance.