# Can I recover boot camp partition after removing it with gpt remove?

Tags: disk-utility, bootcamp, partition, recovery

My old MacBook Pro, A1286, (15in, mid-2012) has an SSD that divided my main boot disk into two partitions, one for Mac OSX (running 10.13, High Sierra) and one for Boot camp (running Windows 10).

The boot partition was always MacOSX.  Unfortunately, after I removed it to try to use it as an external drive, it got damaged in some way after I reinstalled it.  It would not longer boot correctly was identifying as type "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF" when I went into recovery mode and ran `diskutil list` from the terminal.

The bootcamp partition was still bootable though.

In my attempts to repair my boot partition I came across this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262457/how-do-i-recover-fix-my-os-x-partition) that seemed to be very similar to what was happening to me.

I tried to follow the steps laid out by @klanomath.  Two problems arose those:

1. I still got an error when I tried to verify the disk with `diskutil verifyDisk disk0` (Specifically: Error: -69808: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup Underlying error: 1: POSIX reports: Operation not permitted)
2. In trying to rebuild the partitions I removed all of them from disk0, and then tried to add them back.  It seemed to go ok, but now the bootcamp partition is not recognized.

Does anyone know who to restore a bootcamp partition using gpt or another method without losing the data in the partition?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is a image of the output of diskutil list
[image]

EDIT 2:

Progress - After @David Anderson pointed out an error (thank you for catching that) in the value I entered for the type, my partition for boot camp is recognized as "Windows Basic Data" type.
[image]

And in Startup Disk, it shows as an option
[image]

But unfortunately, when I try using Startup Disk to use it as the boot disk it won't boot still. And says;

"No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

When I turn on the computer and hold down the option key it doesn't show up as an option either.
[image]

Here is the output from  `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`

[image]

And here is the output from `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII";dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=1 | vis -cw;echo`

[image]

UPDATE:

After updating the type of the partition to `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` it shows as an option to boot into if I restart the computer.  But it does not show in Startup Disk.  And when I try to boot to disk0s2 it will hang at the apple logo with a full progress bar.

I believe I have an idea of what may be complicating my situation.  First a little further explanation of how my drives were arranged in the computer originally.

Originally I had an HDD in the computer running OSX (10.8 I believe), then after awhile I added a second drive, an SSD (disk0) and partitioned it to have a OSX partition (disk0s2) and a bootcamp partition (disk0s3).  The SSD OSX became my primary boot partition and the old HDD I used for storage, but I never removed OSX completely off of it (now listed as disk1 in diskutil)

A little ago I needed to be able to use the Bootcamp partition but did not have the power adapter for the mbp, so I tried to remove the SSD and use it as an external on a different computer, that did not work, and after I placed it back into the original mbp is when disk0 s2 wasn't being recognized and I started to try to fix it.  This is when I messed up my bootcamp partition and then I posted on here.

I believe the OSX Recovery that I have been using is from the original HDD which only had 10.8 on it.  And after doing some research it seems that maybe 10.8 can't identify the newer OSX partition (disk0s2) and that is why in Startup Disk I don't see it, but if I reboot the computer it does show up as an option.

[image]
Here are the outputs that you asked for.

```
sw_vers

ls -l /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot/BCD

diskutil list
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and include the model/year of your Mac. Also, include the version of Windows.

Comment: ok, I added the model/year and Windows version.  Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: What does *"bootcamp partition is not recognized"* mean? Does this mean you can not view the Bootcamp volume files in the Finder? Or, something else? Can you post the output from the command `diskutil list`?

Comment: By "bootcamp partition is not recognized" I mean that it no longer shows as a boot option.  I can't boot the computer at all, so I can't see Finder at all, but it also isn't recognized in Disk Utility.  It just says "disk0s3" and is greyed out and says "not mounted"

Comment: Have you noticed when you entered your data that you entered `EBD040A2` instead of entering `EBD0A0A2`? In other words, you entered a `4` instead of an `A`. The correct value is documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition)

Comment: Edit your question and include the output from the commands `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII";dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=1 | vis -cw` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`.

Comment: Thank you for catching my typo.  It helped in that diskutil now sees it as a bootcamp partition, but still won't boot to it.

Comment: I asked you to enter `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII";dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=1 | vis -cw`, but instead you entered `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII";dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=1 vis -cw`. In other words, you omitted the `|` character. Try again, but this time enter `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII";dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=1 | vis -cw;echo` instead.

Comment: my apologies for my mistake.  I tried again and posted the image.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The value of `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` in your GPT is incorrect. The value you should have used is `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: You should make all the corrections to the GPT before making the changes given in this answer.

Your `disk0` is not hybrid partition, which means the output from the command `fdisk /dev/disk0` will probably appear as shown below.

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60801/255/63 [976773168 sectors]
Offset: 0   Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 255  63 - 1023 255  63 [         1 -  976773167] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

To create a hybrid partitioned disk, you need to edit the Master Boot Record (MBR) table on `disk0`. This can be accomplished by using the command given below.

```
fdisk -f /dev/zero -e /dev/disk0
```

In this case, the command `fdisk` is interactive. Enter the data given in the first column of the table below.

| User Entry | Type | Default Value | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `edit 1` | command | no | Edit first table entry |
| `ee` | parameter | yes | Partition id |
| `n` | parameter | yes | Edit in CHS mode? |
| `1` | parameter | no | Partition offset |
| `409639` | parameter | no | Partition size |
| `edit 2` | command | no | Edit second table entry |
| `ff` | parameter | no | Partition id |
| `n` | parameter | yes | Edit in CHS mode? |
| `409640` | parameter | yes | Partition offset |
| `913864664` | parameter | no | Partition size |
| `edit 3` | command | no | Edit third table entry |
| `07` | parameter | no | Partition id |
| `n` | parameter | yes | Edit in CHS mode? |
| `914274304` | parameter | yes | Partition offset |
| `62498816` | parameter | no | Partition size |
| `flag 3` | command | no | Flag the third table entry as bootable |
| `print` | command | no | Print loaded MBR partition table |
| `quit` | command | no | Quit edit of current MBR, saving current changes |
| `y` | parameter | no | Confirm save to disk, then quit? |

The probable output from the `fdisk` interactive command `print` given in the above table or the command `fdisk /dev/disk0` is given below.

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60801/255/63 [976773168 sectors]
Offset: 0   Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: FF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  913864664] Xenix BBT   
*3: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 914274304 -   62498816] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Question though, and sorry if I am being ignorant, but am I trying to create a hybrid drive or maybe the better question is do I need to?  My original goal was to be able to salvage data from my disk0s2 partition.  In trying to do that I messed up my bootcamp partition (disk0s3).  With your help, disk util sees disk0s3 as a bootcamp, though I can't boot into it, and disk0s2 is recognized as a boot option when I restart, but again won't actually boot (it hangs at the apple logo with a full progress bar).  Do I need a hybrid drive to be able to boot into either of them?

Comment: Post the output from the commands `sw_vers` and `ls -l /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot/BCD`. Also, if the output from `diskutil list` has changed, then post the new output. I ask for this output, so I can better answer the questions in your previous comment.

Comment: I added the outputs, and some more background into my setup.  Thanks again for all your assistance

Comment: You need a hybrid partitioned drive only to get Windows to boot.  You will probably need other repairs beyond hybrid partitioning in order to get Windows to boot. For example, you probably erased the BIOS boot code in the Master Boot Record (MBR).

Comment: You could try upgrading from Mountain Lion to at least Sierra. This would allow you to mount APFS volumes. If successful, you could save files off the APFS volumes. Or, you could try booting from [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/mac) using *Option-Command-R*. However, you would have to use the command line interface (CLI) to save files.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue after recovering my macOS partition which was changed by OSx recovery. To recover my macOS partition I followed the instruction at following posts

- [Data Not Backed Up, Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff)
- [How do I recover/fix my OS X partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262457/how-do-i-recover-fix-my-os-x-partition)
- [How to fix broken GPT, GUID and unmountable, no type volumes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/how-to-fix-broken-gpt-guid-and-unmountable-no-type-volumes/221119#221119)

Last one was most helpful.

But in this process 1st entry of the partition table changed from MBR was PMBR. I suspect due to this only it is not showing up at the boot time, although it shows up from startup disk.

I will update my answer as I try to make my Bootcamp bootable again.

**Update 1**

I was able to successfully rebuild the MBR by following the step mentioned here and in another [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308824). But it is still not booting.

Here is the output from fdisk.

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60821/255/63 [977105060 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: FF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  618098816] Xenix BBT   
 3: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 618508456 -   45836120] HPFS/QNX/AUX
*4: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 664606720 -  312498176] HPFS/QNX/AUX
```

BCD is present under /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot/

Disk shows up in the startup but does not boot. Am I missing something?