# Unbootable old dualboot Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, recovery, dual-boot

Half a year ago, I got an old Macbook Pro from my dad. I had set up dual boot with Debian. I haven't used the laptop for several months. Now suddenly it didn't want to boot the Debian partition, so I wanted to redo the whole dual boot. Erased the Debian partition and tried to merge it with the main macOS partition. Unsuccessfully. I went for a restart and since then I'm also unable to boot the macOS part. Only recovery mode or live USBs.

So far I'm no super savvy linux power user, but can manage a bit of complexity so I immediately dove into debugging. [Found this series of threads](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff). Went down through all the steps. Disk seems fine now (at least the disk util said so), but Macbook is still unbootable.

Does anyone have any idea what to try out next? My only goal is to extract the data from the macOS partition. Of course willing to disclose any further information upon requests (I'm not sure what would be helpful at this point).

[Another post I made before being aware of this part of SE.](https://superuser.com/questions/1756520/corrupted-boot-partition)

Comment: Was your first step when the mac was bootable to make a full backup?

Comment: I have partial backup, most of the important data is safe, but I'd like to debug this to find out what happened... so no, there unfortunately isn't an option of rolling back to some time machine backup

Comment: Search on here and read carefully q&a like this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/262457/237687

Comment: thanks for the tip, but this one wasn’t really useful, as I had already tried all the step mentioned there

Comment: That was just one as an example, check the others.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked this question had I found an answer in another post :)